# ggadjustedcurves Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing

Tags: r, cox-regression

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status)~Age + strata(Study), data)
```

My study uses factor with 2 levels, all other variables are numerical

`summary(fit)` does give me results with coef and p-values etc.

However, on attempting the curves like this:

```
ggadjustedcurves(fit, variable="Study", data=data, method="average")
```

I get this message:

> Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing

Answer (score 2):

Your data must be in tibble format. Try:
ggadjustedcurves(fit, variable="Study", data=data.frame(data), method="average")